# Xamarin forms - list view DataTemplate with two lines and image

Tags: uitableview, listview, xamarin.forms

I have the following which puts an image at the end of each cell, the problem is that the text is all on the same line and needs to be seperated.

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions = "LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding InfoDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm}'}"
       LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" 
       Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" 
       FontSize="16" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"
       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
       FontSize="14"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding FullAddress}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle }" 
       FontSize="12"/>
                <Image Source="tick.png" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemImageStyle}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"  ></Image>  
            </StackLayout>

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there a way of having the text labels stacked but the image on its own in the center towards the right?

Something like this:
  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH4m7.png]

Comment: use a Grid instead of a StackLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with grid, like this:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding InfoDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm}'}"
                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"
                       FontSize="16" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                       FontSize="14"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding FullAddress}"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle }"
                       FontSize="12"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"
                       Source="tick.png" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemImageStyle}"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"  /> 
            </Grid>

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Works great thanks, is there documentation that you recommend for using the grid system?

Comment: @the_tr00per The official xamarin docs are great ;)

[Xamarin Guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a grid inside yourViewCell. You can adjust the width ratio for the labels/image as you like. In this example it is 70%/30%:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" ...>
        <!-- YOUR LABELS HERE -->
    </StackLayout>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" ... />
</Grid>
```